# Fatal Exception: java.lang.No ClassDefFoundError at com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite

Tags: android, admob

When i update the Android application to support API 28 The app crash in device that run Android 9 and this is the error:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/http/ProtocolVersion;
   at lt.b(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@30000@30000.238272502.238272502:2)
   at ls.a(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@30000@30000.238272502.238272502:1)
   at lu.a(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@30000@30000.238272502.238272502:18)
   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.ar.a(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@30000@30000.238272502.238272502:10)
   at kx.a(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@30000@30000.238272502.238272502:7)
   at kx.run(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@30000@30000.238272502.238272502:2) in firebase Crashlytics
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Apache HTTP client deprecation**
>
> With Android 6.0, we removed support for the Apache HTTP client. **Beginning with Android 9, that library is removed** from the bootclasspath and is not available to apps by default.
>
> To continue using the Apache HTTP client, apps that target Android 9 and above can add the following to their AndroidManifest.xml:
>
> `<uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>`

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-28